# Copy out plain .o files with cmake

Tags: build, cmake

I'm trying to get cmake (on linux) to create some static object (.o) files and install them to an external directory. To that end I have a list, `object_sources`, containing the project path of the sources, and put this in the top level `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(local_objects "")
foreach(file ${object_sources})
    get_filename_component(cur ${file} NAME_WE)
    add_library("${cur}.o" OBJECT ${file})
    list(APPEND local_objects "${cur}.o")
# To confirm these variables are what I think they are:
    message("---> ${cur} | ${file}")
endforeach()

install(
# Also tried FILES, see below.
    TARGETS ${local_objects}
    CONFIGURATIONS Debug
# Also tried nothing instead of 'OBJECTS' (same outcome)
# and LIBRARY (cmake fails on error).
    OBJECTS
    DESTINATION "/some/external/dir"
)
```

With regard to using `FILES`, it cannot work because in fact a `foo.o` is never created, so there is no point in me trying to get the correct project path.

When I get to the actual `make` command in the cmake build directory, it spits out *Built target foo.o*, etc., during the process.  However, as mentioned, no `foo.o` is ever created anywhere, and the `install` creates an `objects-Debug` directory in `/some/external/dir` containing directories for each target using its name (e.g., `foo.o/`) and inside that some more nested directories at the bottom of which is the object I want, with the wrong name: `foo.cpp.o`.

Cmake can structure its build tree however it wants and name its temporaries whatever it likes, but I would really like to be able to ask for a final product object `foo.o` (not `foo.cpp.o`) and have it installed that way.

Is that possible?  I'm beginning to think this is all very contrary to the (implicit) purposes of cmake, and that I should keep these kinds of tasks separate in a shell script or makefile (it takes about three lines in either), and just use cmake for the normative libs and executables.

Or: I believe I could get this to work if I created each object as a static archive (lib.a) instead, but part of the issue here is that would require modifying the build scripts of something else, or else extracting them via a script (in which case I might as well do the whole thing in the script).

Comment: See: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/712#note_834973

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of a good way to do this in CMake, but maybe the least fussy would be to use an [`OBJECT`](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/tutorials/Object-Library) library. This would allow you to get the object files for a target using [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html), more specifically the `TARGET_OBJECTS` expression. This is a minimal example with a single `foo.c` file containing an empty `main`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

project(foo C)

set(SOURCES foo.c)

add_library(foo_obj OBJECT ${SOURCES})

add_executable(foo $<TARGET_OBJECTS:foo_obj>)

set(OBJS $<TARGET_OBJECTS:foo_obj>)
message(STATUS "these are my objects: ${OBJS}") # generator expression printed here, not evaluated yet

add_custom_target(print_foo_objs
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo $<TARGET_OBJECTS:foo_obj>)

set(OBJ_ROOT_DIR $<TARGET_PROPERTY:foo,BINARY_DIR>) 

add_custom_target(copy_foo_objs
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${OBJ_ROOT_DIR}/myobjects/
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different $<TARGET_OBJECTS:foo_obj> ${OBJ_ROOT_DIR}/myobjects/ 
  COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS) # UPDATE
```

Please note that as a generator expression, you will not have access to it during configuration (hence, that `message` will contain the generator expression as it was textually declared), but only during the generation phase.

If you still need to rename the object files (i.e. from `foo.c.o` to `foo.o`) you can maybe call a custom external script to do that for you.
Moreover, there might be issues with cleanup, etc. which will force you to add more custom targets and/or commands (and associated dependencies) to deal with it. Another downside of this approach.

*UPDATE*: `COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS` allows the expansion of lists in the generator expression and it was added in CMake 3.8 and later (see [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html)).

Comment: For the renaming, couldn't you use the `install(... RENAME ...)` command?

Comment: @AlexisWilke That's probably true, but it only works when a single file is installed, correct?

Comment: Yes, the `RENAME` is for one file at a time.

Comment: I am trying this solution in my project and although my object library gets created and executable generated and running, the custom targets (print_foo_objs, copy_foo_objs) don't get invoked.

Comment: @jws the example provided in the answer does not invoke them by default, they have to be specified manually. Otherwise, you can set up the dependencies that suit you or added to the default build target using the `ALL` option (see [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html))

Comment: @compor this works when foo_obj contains less number of sources, when number of sources are more it throws an error . what can be done in that case ?

Comment: @Ragul I'm not sure what you mean less or more number of sources. Can you please clarify?

Comment: When the generator expression $<TARGET_OBJECTS:foo_obj> is replaced with values (path to obj files) the command gets expanded and if it crosses a particular limit , command isn't getting executed and it throws an error.

Comment: @Ragul what is that limit? How many? I cannot replicate this. If you need to expand a list for a generator expression you need to pass `COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS` in the [`add_custom_target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html). See my update above.

Comment: @compor i guess something in the range of 32000 chars.. 
COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS - this works fine but the content length is causing the issue.

Comment: @Ragul maybe you are overexerting this mechanism. Still not sure I understand. You should create a separate issue and describe it in detail. Someone will answer. The comment section has its limits.

Comment: @compor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66884514/how-to-collect-all-object-files-o-of-a-big-project-in-a-particular-directory