# CMake to give (.o) file as output

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I'm trying to get mu C++ code to compile as object file (.o) but I can get it in (.a, .dylib, executable) forms

I've tried this answer: [Copy out plain .o files with cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51988350/copy-out-plain-o-files-with-cmake)

but didn't actually understood the solution and it didn't work either.

how can I achieve this ?

here is my CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(myProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(LIBS_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../libs)

file(GLOB SOURCES
            src/*.cpp
            )

find_library(SQLITE3
             NAMES libsqlite3.0.tbd
             )

MACRO(HEADER_DIRECTORIES return_list)
    FILE(GLOB_RECURSE new_list ${LIBS_DIR}/*.h*)
    SET(dir_list "")
    FOREACH(file_path ${new_list})
        GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(dir_path ${file_path} PATH)
        SET(dir_list ${dir_list} ${dir_path})
    ENDFOREACH()
    LIST(REMOVE_DUPLICATES dir_list)
    SET(${return_list} ${dir_list})
ENDMACRO()

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}_obj OBJECT ${SOURCES})


HEADER_DIRECTORIES(HDR_DIRS)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}_obj PUBLIC
                           ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}
                           ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
                           ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../fmt
                           ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include
                           ${HDR_DIRS}
                           )

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_obj ${SQLITE3})
```

Comment: Do you want to get this result ?  https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-January/042284.html

Comment: @Andrey thanks for your comment, I already tried it but this gave me each file of sources files as .o file. I need the whole executable to be one .o file

Comment: @MazenAk You need the whole "executable" to be an object file, the result of compiling a *single* source file? Why?

Comment: @JaMiT I need to take the output file and use it to compile another executable

Comment: @MazenAk That is what the `.a` form (static library) is for.

Comment: @JaMiT will it work if I want to build one executable depends on multiple libraries (or object files) ? I used to compile all the cpps I have as one cpp file and get the object file to use it later with the final executable compile

Comment: @MazenAk There is something wrong with that sentence structure (making it difficult to parse) but I think the gist is that you are asking if a library can be used as a library is intended to be used. So, yes, it works that way.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot merge multiple translation units into a single object file (is due to the features of the linker (ld util). only to library or elf.

Earlier gcc can to be able to merge several files into a single object file, but this feature was removed